# Does OS installation continues if I close lid

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-systems, kali-linux

I am installing a Kali Linux OS on my PC. Can I close the lid during the installation process?  Please help me with it

PS -  I am in hurry, I m going to another place and I need this PC with me. That's why asked whether to close it or not while the OS is installing

Comment: It will depend on the OS and the hardware.  There is no one correct answer.

Comment: Sir, Do you know specifically about Kali Linux?

Comment: I am looking at a Kali 2019.4 machine here and the power settings are basically the same as my Windows Machine. In the Kali Power Manager, the Suspend tab only allows Suspend - no other option

Comment: Sir, @John It doesn't seem to be an answer to my question. Could you please elaborate

Comment: It seems to be about the same as Windows. Close the lid and processing stops as I and others have noted here.

Comment: What did you finally do? Did you suspend the laptop? Did you take it with you as planned?  Did Kali finish installing?  The time has now passed.  What happened?

Comment: @John The charge is 10% while it's on installation. I think Laptop charge drained before the installation.  Installation not done.

Comment: So then complete the installation, get all working and then check suspend again for proper operation

Answer (score 0):

Since you are moving the computer I assume a laptop, and no, the OS will not continue to install. The laptop will suspend and stop the install.  Wireless might keep going, but applications will suspend.

Comment: @Keltari Mentioned something else sir, I am getting confused

Comment: The point of suspending is to stop things and allow the computer to basically stop, not keep running, and permit moving. On a machine with a HDD, the heads park and the drive does not keep working

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance it will stop, but worst comes to worst you just start with a fresh install. If you're going somewhere, I'd close it to protect the laptop, especially if it has a HDD.

Answer (score 0):

Well, closing the lid actually suspends making it to halt all activities **unless** you chose what happens when the lid closes! As in Kali-2019.3 release there's actually an option in `gnome-tweaks` which gives you the control as to what happens when the lid closes c: hope that helps